# How does the product construction of the Stone-Cech compactification work?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

Wikipedia's article on the Stone-Cech compactification gives several constructions of it, one which is this:

> One attempt to construct the Stone–Čech compactification of $X$ is to take the closure of the image of $X$ in $${\displaystyle \prod C}$$
>   where the product is over all maps from $X$ to compact Hausdorff spaces $C$. This works intuitively but fails for the technical reason that the collection of all such maps is a proper class rather than a set. There are several ways to modify this idea to make it work; for example, one can restrict the compact Hausdorff spaces $C$ to have underlying set $P(P(X))$ (the power set of the power set of $X$), which is sufficiently large that it has cardinality at least equal to that of every compact Hausdorff set to which $X$ can be mapped with dense image.

Forget the caveat about sets and proper classes, I'm just trying to understand the idea.  My question is, what does ${\displaystyle \prod C}$ mean?  I don't understand "the product is over all maps from $X$ to compact Hausdorff spaces $C$".  What exactly are we taking a product of?

Are we taking a Cartesian product of compact Hausdorff spaces, or are we taking some kind of product of maps, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set* of all continuous maps $f:X\to C$ where $C$ can be any compact Hausdorff space.  Then the product in question is the product $$\prod_{f\in S}\operatorname{codomain}(f).$$  That is, the index set of the product is $S$, and the factor corresponding to each map $f:X\to C$ in $S$ is the space $C$.  This is just an ordinary product of topological spaces.

Denoting this product by $P$, there is a canonical map $F:X\to P$.  Namely, for each $f\in S$, the $f$-coordinate of $F$ is just $f$.  That is, $F(x)(f)=f(x)$.  The Stone-Cech compactification of $X$ is then (modulo set-theoretic issues) the closure of the image of this map $F$.

*OK, it's actually only a class, but that's not important here.

Comment: Wow, that is one gigantic product.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan the nice thing is that we can ignore this pseudo-construction and prove that we only need $w(X)$ many copies of $[0,1]$. Still quite large in general but not "class"-large. The only pedagogical benefit is that you get the universal extension property without work, basically for free.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What is $w(X)$?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan the “weight” of $X$, the smallest infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that $X$ has a base of size $\kappa$. So second countable spaces have $w(X)=\aleph__0$, the Sorgenfrey line has weight  continuum. Etc.